# Как передать json данные в параметр post запроса ajax через form

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Есть ajax запрос:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://142.20.99.99:8081/pggrw/v1',
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: false
    },
    crossDomain: true,
    data: JSON.stringify({
        "method": "subscriberInfo",
        "params": [{ "msisdn": "99999999" }],
        "id": "1"
    }),
    success: function (msg) {
        var data = JSON.stringify(msg);
        $('#go').html(data);
    },
    error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('POST failed.');
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
});
```

Как передать параметр "msisdn" из инпута через форму в параметры post, при этом остальные данные не меняя.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ищем инпут

```
var input = document.getElementById('my-input-id'); // по id
```

или

```
var input = document.querySelector('my-input-class'); //по классу
```

возможно вы любым другим способом "прицелитесь" к инпуту. Может через data атрибут.
Далее вставляем значение в параметры:

```
"params": [{ "msisdn": input.value }],
```

должно работать)

Comment: Большое спасибо @Taarim, очень помогли.